# Is it ideal for the Name Node to also be the Secondary Name Node?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am practicing a hadoop cluster via Raspberry Pi,, according to this tutorial(http://www.widriksson.com/raspberry-pi-hadoop-cluster/) he sets the node1 in his hadoop masters file configuration which is confusing as he also uses node to start the hadoop daemons. I want to know the reason for his configuration as well

P.S. - Just ctrl+f the masters

Comment: It's not ideal. With Hadoop 2.x, Active Namenode will take over Namenode role if Namenode is down. Have a look at related SE question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970461/name-node-vs-secondary-name-node/34716750#34716750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No It is not ideal. It is up to you how to configure your cluster. In this tutorial, author decided to use `node1` as P-NN and S-NN at the same time. Keep in mind that RPi Hadoop Cluster is suitable just for development and test and not production environment.

Pros and Cons of running Primary NameNode and Secondary NameNode on a separate machine(Based on [This article](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/multi-host-secondarynamenode-configuration/) from Cloudera):

> 1.Scalability. Creating the system snapshot requires about as much memory as the NameNode itself occupies. Since the memory available to
>   the NameNode process is a primary limit on the size of the distributed
>   filesystem, a large-scale cluster will require most or all of the
>   available memory for the NameNode.
>
> 2.Durability. When the SecondaryNameNode creates a checkpoint, it does so in a separate copy of the filesystem metadata. Moving this
>   process to another machine also creates a copy of the metadata file on
>   an independent machine, increasing its durability.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the answer. But what will be the effect of this configuration? Can you speak out the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada I have edited my answer with pros and cons.

Comment: I think another reason for seperation is in case the node 1 which the "name node" fails then there is an available secondary name node that it can point to

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada Secondary NameNode is not a backup for NameNode.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but Secondary Name Node runs when the Name Node has a failure right?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada No It is wrong. It is not a backup node. Read this for the secret story behind S-NN: http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/secondary-namenode---what-it-really-do/

Comment: Thanks for everything

Comment: I get the idea of the blog, but it can also be used as a backup for the namenode on such cases where the namenode malfunctions or failure right?

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada There is another node called BackupNode which does this. S-NN is just a Checkpoint Node.

Comment: Ok,, thanks! Wow, you are very knowledgeable I'm impressed